# regex in Laravel, how to allow NULL value

Tags: regex, laravel

hy guys, i want remove all special charachters with regex in my input field,
I want allow numeric, alpha, white spaces (i menage that) and I want to allow that field under regex can be NULL (empty value)

My code

```
//
public function find_opgs(Request $request){
            
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), 
        [  
            'firm_place' => 'regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect()->route('show_opg_search')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }

    ...do something
}
```

when I try this solution and leave my input field empty, I get message
"the firm place format is invalid"

I want that I can pass null throught regex, and allow whitespaces, alpha_num...

Have any ideas?

Comment: Regex only operates on strings, you can't check if a value is null with it.

Comment: Did you try to use `nullable`? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-nullable

Comment: ooo didnt know that, but why it bounce me back "the firm place format is invalid"


didnt try with nullable, i will, thx

Answer (score 0):

thx guys i combined STAs answear with olegs and it works now!
thx a lot!
nullable was saviour